# Understanding notify method in HotSpot

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I was trying to understand how notify wakes up a thread and faced some misunderstanding about implementation details in hotspot (jdk8).

We have `wait`/`notify` declared as a native methods inside `Object` and they are implemented here: [wait](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/hotspot/file/37240c1019fd/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#l1462) and [notify](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/hotspot/file/37240c1019fd/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#l1697). Since `static int Knob_MoveNotifyee = 2 ;` I expected that [the following code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/hotspot/file/37240c1019fd/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#l1754) is responsible for performing wake up:

```
 if (Policy == 2) {      // prepend to cxq
     // prepend to cxq
     if (List == NULL) {
         iterator->_next = iterator->_prev = NULL ;
         _EntryList = iterator ;
     } else {
        iterator->TState = ObjectWaiter::TS_CXQ ;
        for (;;) {
            ObjectWaiter * Front = _cxq ;
            iterator->_next = Front ;
            if (Atomic::cmpxchg_ptr (iterator, &_cxq, Front) == Front) {
                break ;
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

But the thing is the method `void ObjectWaiter::notify` is wrapped into `Thread::SpinAcquire (&_WaitSetLock, "WaitSet - notify");`  /`Thread::SpinRelease (&_WaitSetLock) ;`.

1. Why do we have CAS when prepending a dequeued thread from waiting queue to `cxq`? There seems no contention there since we acquired `_WaitSetLock` already.
2. Who does modify the `JavaThread` state? We have `iterator->wait_reenter_begin(this);` [at the end of `void ObjectWaiter::notify`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/hotspot/file/37240c1019fd/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#l1796), but this does not do `set_thread_status(java_thread, java_lang_Thread::RUNNABLE);` like in [wait_reenter_end](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/hotspot/file/37240c1019fd/src/share/vm/services/threadService.hpp#l541)

Comment: 1. I don't read C++ well but I assume what is going on is that all Java threads blocked on a monitor are stored in a list (queue).  And to operate on that list requires mutex.  That's why `_WaitSetLock` is called first.  So there are two concepts of thread safety here.  One is for the list of threads that are being manipulated, but the second is for the data structure that we are manipulating.

Comment: 2. And for thread state I assume the JVM uses the OS implementation of threads and that the OS directly sets the state of those threads.

Comment: @markspace 2. But when the `wait_reenter_begin` is called the state of the thread is set to the `BLOCKED_ON_MONITOR_ENTER` explicitly [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/hotspot/file/37240c1019fd/src/share/vm/services/threadService.hpp#l515). But when the thread is Runnable its status is (obviously?) `RUNNABLE`. I would expect that even if JVM uses OS threads it should set the status to `RUNNABLE` somewhere anyway, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `_WaitSetLock` protects `_WaitSet` only (the list of threads called `wait` on that object monitor). Meanwhile `_cxq` can be concurrently accessed not only from `notify`, but also from other functions, in particular, `ObjectMonitor::enter` and `exit`.
2. `notify` does not modify the thread status. The status changes when the target thread leaves [`JVM_MonitorWait`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/06dcd58caf4a/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l555). It is done by [`JavaThreadInObjectWaitState`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/06dcd58caf4a/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l558) destructor which implicitly calls [`~JavaThreadStatusChanger()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/06dcd58caf4a/src/share/vm/services/threadService.hpp#l437).

Comment: If a thread that is in the `WaitSet` is interrupted is it pushed into `cxq` or `EntryList`? Or it is simply removed from the `WaitSet`?

Comment: @St.Antario An interrupted thread reenters lock via `ObjectMonitor::enter`. As far as I see, a thread entering a lock pushes itself to `_cxq` first.